# Declaring Dynamic 2D array from CIN

Tags: c++, arrays

I am looking to change the code which I found here of the game TOH [here](http://www.cpp-home.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=4251)

I would like to have it to ask for How Many Disks... then if inputted 3. I would then change the [8]s to [3] all over the arrays inthe codes. Or is there any more better approach?

I was researching and found [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) but it doesnt work that way in 2d arrays.

How do I use vectors in here.. to change the rows [8] to user inputted..

```
struct World{

   int t[3][8];
   int cursor;
   int chosen;

};
```

where my int main is the one asking for "How many rows..."?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`std::vector<std::vector<int>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead. This handles the dynamic allocation automatically.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    //
    // *** Validation of input omitted: you must do this. ***
    //
    size_t rows;
    std::cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
    std::cin >> rows;

    std::cout << "Enter number of columns: ";
    size_t columns;
    std::cin >> columns;

    std::vector<std::vector<int> > ints(rows, std::vector<int>(columns));

    for (size_t ri = 0; ri < rows; ri++)
    {
        for (size_t ci = 0; ci < columns; ci++)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter value for [" << ri << ", " << ci << "]: ";
            std::cin >> ints[ri][ci];
        }
    }

    for (size_t ri = 0; ri < ints.size(); ri++)
    {
        for (size_t ci = 0, size = ints[ri].size(); ci < size; ci++)
        {
            std::cout << "["
                      << ri
                      << ", "
                      << ci
                      << "]="
                      << ints[ri][ci]
                      << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```